# Change color to different php result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So, I got a php file where I'm having an array like`$status=array("onhold" => "Asteptare", "canceled" => "Anulata", "complete" => "Finalizata");`

where the result is displayed in `<td>".$status[$row['status']]."</td>`

I want to make a jQuery script which makes these results have different colors like: onhold to have an orange color, canceled to have a red color and complete to have a green color. I have no ideea how to create it.

Tried to make something with $($status).change(function(){
...
}) but didn't work.

Can someone pls help?

Comment: You can also use css instead of jquery..just use class name as onhold, canceled, complete...set their property in css and add class in html through echo

Comment: yes it seemed like this was a better idea, Thank you. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your HTML to this -

```
<td class=\"".$row['status']."\">".$status[$row['status']]."</td>
```

Now every TD will get a class with the name of its status.

and on your CSS add classes -

```
.onhold { 
   color: orange;
}
.canceled{ 
   color: red;
}
.complete{ 
   color: green;
}
```

Comment: what if $status[$row['status']] is returning value instead of key? like this is returning Asteptare but not onhold?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya Then you'd just use the key... which in this case is `$row['status']`.

Comment: Yes...now looks ok :)

Answer (score -1):

first try to show it in the table like this :

```
<td id=\"".$status[$row['status']]."\">".$status[$row['status']]."</td>
```

now the jquery code could be like this :

```
if($status[$row['status']]=="Anulata"){
echo "$(#".$status[$row['status']].").css('color','red');";
}
```

Comment: It's better to use classes for it, not ID.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thank you, will be back with the result

Comment: You can't use $status[$row['status']] in script without <?php ?>

Comment: You are mixing PHP and JS ... This cant work. Moreover using `class` is better than `id` in this situation.

Comment: it's just an idea , trying to make him understand the main principle

Comment: The fact is that's bad practice. So its not going to help.

Comment: It's not a good solution. If it needs to print out some similar arrays like that, the id will be duplicated.